# Oracle "NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION ERROR-00979"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Below is my PL/SQL Oracle code. It prints the year in which max number of employees got hired and also prints the no of employees joined each month in that year.

If I execute the below code without the for-loop part it generates an error:

> not a group by function error.

What can be the reason am I missing something obvious?

```
declare

      v_year  number(4);
      v_c     number(2);
begin
      select  to_char(hire_date,'yyyy') into v_year
      from  employees
      group by to_char(hire_date,'yyyy')
      having count(*) = 
             ( select  max( count(*))
               from  employees
               group by to_char(hire_date,'yyyy')); // gets the year where max employees joined
               
      dbms_output.put_line('Year : ' || v_year);

      for month in 1 .. 12
      loop
          select  count(*) into v_c
          from employees
          where  to_char(hire_date,'mm') = month and to_char(hire_date,'yyyy') = v_year;
          
          dbms_output.put_line('Month : ' || to_char(month) || ' Employees : ' || to_char(v_c));

     end loop;          

end;
```

Below is the code without for-loop:

```
declare

      v_year  number(4);
      v_c     number(2);
begin
      select  to_char(hire_date,'yyyy') into v_year
      from  employees
      group by to_char(hire_date,'yyyy')
      having count(*) = 
             ( select  max( count(*))
               from  employees
               group by to_char(hire_date,'yyyy'));
               
      dbms_output.put_line('Year : ' || v_year);
end;
```

It generates the following error:

> Error report - ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression ORA-06512: at line 6
> 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:

Comment: Please don't tag other RDBM's - SQL Server != Oracle.

Comment: Sorry about that ! corrected. This is the first time I'm posting a question.

Comment: Are you sure that the query gives that error(there seems no problem with the query except for the case multiple year returns, then it won't be possible to use INTO clause within a SELECT statement)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PL/SQL for this. Also, your SELECT ... INTO will fail if its query returns more than one row, which it would if there were two or more years with the same maximum number of employees hired.

```
select to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(hire_date, 'MM'), count(*)
from employees
group by rollup(to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(hire_date, 'MM'))
having to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY') =
    (select to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY')
       from employees
      group by to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY')
      having count(*) =
         (select max(count(*))
            from employees
           group by to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY')))
order by to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(hire_date, 'MM')
```

P.S. I get the same error as you when I run your second example (no loop) in SQL Developer, but I do not get an error when I run it in SQL*Plus. SQL*Plus reports only "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."

Comment: Thanks, Dale. I'm having a lot of trouble with the HTML required to format my posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better to rewrite the code using concurrent loops with year for the outer and month for the inner one through use of arrays such as

```
DECLARE
  v_year  OWA.nc_arr;
  v_month OWA.nc_arr;
  y       INT := 0;
  m       INT := 0;    
BEGIN
  FOR yr IN
    (
      SELECT hire_year
        FROM( SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'yyyy') AS hire_year, 
                     DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS dr
                FROM employees
               GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'yyyy'))
       WHERE dr = 1
    )
  LOOP
    y := y + 1;
    v_year(y) := yr.hire_year;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Year'||y||' : ' || v_year(y));

      FOR m IN 1 .. 12
      LOOP
          SELECT COUNT(*)
            INTO v_month(m)
            FROM employees
           WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'yyyy'))=v_year(y)
             AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'mm'))= m;
          
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Month : ' || m || ' Employees : ' || to_char(v_month(m)));
     END LOOP; 
  END LOOP;  
END;
/
```

where analytic function is used for the year loop, since there might be more than one year, and multiple(12) variables will be needed for the month loop per each year.